# setTime Carbon also affexts other variable

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have Carbon Object Date which I change the time for a start_date and end_date, what happens is it both becomes the same thing even though I saved it on a seperate variable.

Input

```
    $this->temp_mon_start = $date->setTime(8,0);
    $this->temp_mon_end = $date->setTime(3,0);  
    dd($this->temp_mon_start, $this->temp_mon_end);
```

Output

```
   date: 2021-11-15 03:00:00.0 Asia/Singapore (+08:00)
   date: 2021-11-15 03:00:00.0 Asia/Singapore (+08:00)
```

It appears it saves the last setTime on the `$date` variable, which I don't know what is causing the issue. I'm using Laravel and Carbon. Is there any possible alternative on this? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Carbon works that way. It does not create a new instance but rather changes existing one.

So insted of using:

```
$this->temp_mon_start = $date->setTime(8,0);
```

you can use:

```
$this->temp_mon_start = $date->copy()->setTime(8,0);
```

copy() method creates new instance of Carbon object.

Comment: Didn't know about the copy(). This solved it, thank you!

Comment: See in the doc the difference bewteen `Carbon` and `CarbonImmutable` (inherited from the native PHP `DateTime` and `DateTimeImmutable`), with the mutable object `setTime()` modify the object and return `$this` so you're always referring the same instance, with immutable `setTime()` create an new object.